# CMD - Pressing enter repeats last command

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Okay so everytime I only press enter to a `set /p input` command it always repeats the last command I entered.

Is there a way to rather make CMD maybe echo Error when you press enter to a `set /p` command?

Comment: [EDIT] your question and add the complete batch file

Comment: do `set INPUT=` before the `set /p`?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to rather make CMD maybe echo Error when you press
>   enter to a set /p command?

`set /p` leaves the previous value unchanged, if you just press enter. You can use that behaviour:

```
:loop
  set "input=Error"
  set /p "input=prompt: "
  echo %input%
goto :loop
```